# Is there a way to scroll to the previous input method in fcitx?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, input-method, fcitx

In `fcitx` one can set shortcut to scroll to the next input method (e.g. Ctrl + Shift). However, sometimes I need to switch constantly between two adjacent input methods (e.g. Chinese and Japanese), while I have multiple input methods.

In Windows and MacOS there is also a shortcut to switch to the previous input method, in addition to "switch to the next input method". However I don't seem to find such an option in `fcitx`. Did I overlook something? This is quite inconvenient.